# Linq Dynamic Query Issue - Operator 'OR' incompatible with operand types 'Boolean' and 'String'

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am currently trying to define a dynamic query in Linq but I am receiving the following error:
[image]

My Query is the following:

```
valuesList = valuesList.Where("(position=1 OR value LIKE '%3%')")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-
You cannot pass string inside a linq statement

```
 valuesList = valuesList.Where(x=>x.position == 1 || x.value.Contains(3))
```

Comment: The reason why I was using a string inside the linq statement was because as you can see my query has two conditions but in some cases I wanted it to only consider one of the conditions. Can this be achieved using dynamic linq?

Comment: Create a if else condition. See if the query contains one and if query contains other.

Comment: Why not have a look at using the IQueryable methods to dynamically "build" your query?

Comment: Also for a quick fix just put some more brackets in your original query, but it's an unlikely case that the best way would be with dynamic strings.